# Delete item from ListView clicking on delete-button

Tags: android, android-listview, delete-row

I need to delete from ListView (and DB too) an item clicked from a list.

To do this task, I don't use a contextual menu but I built a custom adapter,
in this adapter "row.xml" there are two buttons "Delete" and "Edit".

So, how can I delete the item selected from de ListView and from the DB too?

...with setTag() I set the ID of the clicked element to the relative button, and than?

How can I remove from the db?

This is my adapter:

```
package com.prendonota;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prendonota.activeRecord.Nota;

public class ListaNotaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Nota> {

    public Nota nota;
    public OnClickListener crudListeners;

    /**
     * Costruttore ereditato
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public ListaNotaAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Nota> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }       





    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = null;
        final View delete;
        final View edit;

        //*** prima di tutto è necessario crearsi un oggetto inflater che
        //*** intrinsecamente associ il contesto attuale su cui si sta agendo
        //*** e il servizio che si è richiesto "layout_inflater"
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //*** una volta che ho l'oggetto inflater che associa contesto+servizio posso procedere
        //*** nell'identificazione dell'xml da usare
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null );

        //*** una volta che ho la vista relativa al contesto attuale e relativa all'xml desiderato per layout
        //*** mi richiamo i propri elementi interni a cui associare i dati dell'oggetto item di turno
        TextView data       = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_data);
        TextView oggetto    = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_oggetto);
        delete  = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.button_row_delete);
        edit    = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.button_row_edit);

        //*** prende l'oggetto nell'array "Nota[] objects" passato in argomento
        //*** dato il proprio indice di posizione
        nota = getItem(position);

        //**** in fine associo agli appositi oggetti "TextView" i rispettivi valori
        data.setText(nota.get_dataInserimentoModifica());
        oggetto.setText(nota.get_oggetto());

        //*** poi associo i tag ai relativi pulsanti "Delete" e "Edit"
        delete.setTag(nota.get_id());
        edit.setTag(nota.get_id());

        //*** assegnazione dei listeners ai rispettivi pulsanti
        delete.setOnClickListener(crudListeners);
        edit.setOnClickListener(crudListeners);

        //*** inizializzo la variabile crudListeners che gestisce i listeners sui pulsanti
        crudListeners = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int idnota = (Integer)v.getTag();
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("ID nota ").append(idnota);
                if(v.getId()==delete.getId()){
                    msg.append(" DELETE");
                }else{
                    msg.append(" EDIT");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };      

        //*** torno la vista che finirà dentro "setAdapter()"
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an adapter then there is no need to delete the item from the list it self. you have to delete the item from the DB using the `poistion` you are reciving in `getView` in your `onClick` method.

When you have remove the object from the DB call the `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter to update the list with the new set of data.

Answer (score 1):

1) Keep a field reference to the List objects in your adapter - for example:

`private ArrayList<Nota>list`

2) Create a final int reference to the position in your getView() method, something like

`final int positionFinal`

3) When you click the Delete button, use the following code:

```
list.removeItem(positionFinal);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope this is clear enough, didn't want to copy and paste your code just to make minor and hard to see alterations to it.
If you need to add animations to removing list items and the ability to sort them by dragging and dropping check out this free library: [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview)

Good luck!

Comment: hi npace thanks about your anwser. I wrote the code that delete the item selected with your way, but how is possible to refresh de list from the class "public class ListaNotaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Nota>"?I know that "notifyDataSetChanged()" work in these case...

Answer (score 0):

In the onClickListener from your listener (crudListeners) just remove the element from the database AND from your adapter's data (it would be your List object).
Then just call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.
hope it helps

Comment: hi Perroloco, thanks for your answer, so in my case, i'm going to delete the item with a listener defined **inside my custom adapter class**, and so i have not a direct reference to the "adapter" object if not through "this"...but it doesn't work.